# How to show Selected item In Multiple text box

Tags: php

```
<td > 
<select data-placeholder="---Choose Stone Color---" style="width:250px;" name="stn_color[]" id="stn_color" class="chzn-select" multiple tabindex="11" readonly disabled="disabled">      
  <?php
    $r1 = '';
    $SLCT_st = "SELECT * FROM master_stone WHERE statu_s='active'";
    //echo $SLCT;
    $QURY_st = mysql_query($SLCT_st);

    while($FTCH_st = mysql_fetch_object($QURY_st))
    {

        $r1.= $FTCH_st->master_stone_id.",";
        //$stone_name=$FTCH_st->master_stone_name;
    }

    $r2 = rtrim($r1,",");
    $SLCT_stn = "SELECT * FROM master_stone WHERE master_stone_id ='$master_stone_id'";
    $QURY_stn = mysql_query($SLCT_stn);
    $FTCH_stn = mysql_fetch_object($QURY_stn);
    $v1 = explode(",",$r2);
    $v2 = explode(",",$FTCH_stn->master_stone_id) ;
    foreach($v2 as $test1)
    {
         $SLCT_stn1 = "SELECT * FROM master_stone WHERE master_stone_id ='$test1'";
        //echo $SLCT_stn1."<br >";
         $QURY_stn1 = mysql_query($SLCT_stn1);
         $FTCH_stn1 = mysql_fetch_object($QURY_stn1);
         echo "<option ".(in_array($test1, $v1)?"selected":"")." value='$test1'>$FTCH_stn1->master_stone_name</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

strong text

Here I'm fetching the multiselect value from table.If I selected 4 values from multiselect dropdown which can be insert successfully in table.But If i fetch the value from that column means it shows only one value.How to shows the all value.

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure this is correct `statu_s`?

Comment: Yes I think so. statu_s is the column name.All values are in active state only

Comment: are you talking abt $r1

Comment: `mysql_fetch_object` function gets a row from the mysql_query() function and returns an object on success, or FALSE on failure or when there are no more rows. so i think you are failing in fetching 2 row